# Razor - How to prevent unwanted line break in view source when @{} or @() was used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Whenver I use @{ } or @( ) in the webpage and run it from Visual Studio, then in the web-browser, i noticed in the view source are are line break before the @{ syntax and another line break after the } syntax.

Is there a way to prevent line break so the view source become easier to read?

Thanks...

Comment: An example what you are trying to do and what you are currently getting would help. "*Easier to read*" is subjective...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything you can do regarding the line breaks.  The formatting is as per source file after its been compiled and rendered from the server side.

The effect to the end user in terms of layout is nothing as its not a html line break: `<br>`

You can put server side code in-line as per the example below which will stop the line spacing:

```
a<br/>@{ /*some code 1 that does not produce a line break*/}
b<br />
c<br />
@{ 
    /*some code 2 that does produce line breaks*/
}
d<br />
e<br />
```

this will produce the following:

```
a<br />
b<br />
c<br />

d<br />
e<br />
```